# CDN don't show new image

Tags: php, image, cdn

I have small problem with CDN. When I upload new image on my website in background scripts generate smaller version of this image and move it to another folder. When i want to load this file by CDN it's not available but if I delete "cdn." from link image work. Main image work without any problems but smaller version didn't via cdn. Could someone tell me why?

Link to normal version looks like:

http://cdn.example.com/uploads/image.ext - via CDN / Work

http://example.com/uploads/image.ext / Work

**Link to smaller version looks like:**

http://cdn.example.com/uploads/thumbnails/image.ext - via CDN / Didn't work

http://example.com/uploads/thumbnails/image.ext / Work

To do smaller version I copied normal to thumbnails folder and resizing it by

```
$image2 = new SimpleImage();
$image2->load('./uploads/thumbnails/image.ext');
$image2->resize(90,140);
$image2->save('./uploads/thumbnails/image.ext');
```

Comment: What CDN are you using? This sounds like an issue you need to take up with their technical support people.

Comment: Coinshost - its my CDN provider. When I text to support they told me: "We do not provide software support services. You have to check your settings"

Comment: you should do versioning on CDN assets, if you update an image, the CDN cached the old version of copy, one workaround is to append query string such as `?v=2` at the end

Answer (score 0):

I done it like that: when I load image from my server then cdn cached it and now i can load image from cdn. I need to do this operation once but now if else is done every refresh. Someone have a proposition how to edit that?

```
$src = 'http://cdn.example.com/uploads/thumbnails/image.ext';
    if (@getimagesize($src))
        $img_prop = array('src' => 'http://cdn.example.com/uploads/thumbnails/image.ext', 'height' => 140, 'width' => 90, 'alt' => htmlspecialchars('title'));
    else
        $img_prop = array('src' => 'http://example.com/uploads/thumbnails/image.ext', 'height' => 140, 'width' => 90, 'alt' => htmlspecialchars('title'));
```